# where can i find a list of all built in matchers for Jasmine expect

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am trying to find a list of all existing Jasmine expect matchers like 'toContain' etc...

Where can I find this? i have searched for a while but couldn't find something like an api.

Jasmine site doesn't have any sort of an ordered list too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find it in [wiki](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) on GitHub.

Comment: not anymore :( wiki's been deprecated in favor of unnavigable documentation.

Comment: Below is the link, you can find the complete list of Matchers for Jasmine.

https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find this handy document on a related project :) https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers

---

In there they name the default ones:

```
expect(fn).toThrow(e);
expect(instance).toBe(instance);
expect(mixed).toBeDefined();
expect(mixed).toBeFalsy();
expect(number).toBeGreaterThan(number);
expect(number).toBeLessThan(number);
expect(mixed).toBeNull();
expect(mixed).toBeTruthy();
expect(mixed).toBeUndefined();
expect(array).toContain(member);
expect(string).toContain(substring);
expect(mixed).toEqual(mixed);
expect(mixed).toMatch(pattern);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [**Included Matchers**](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers) section of the **[Introduction doc](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html)** lists, describes, and shows them in action. For example:

```
it("The 'toBe' matcher compares with ===", function() {
    var a = 12;
    var b = a;

    expect(a).toBe(b);
    expect(a).not.toBe(null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First way.

You can find the list by watching `expect()` object in debugging tool, such as Firebug or something else.

Secong way:

Look at the sources of Jasmine.

Comment: how can i watch expect()? the browser window that opens when the tests run closes so fast

Comment: @lobengula3rd;  put an explicit breakpoint,ie. `debugger;` above the line of `expect()` expression

Answer (score 0):

A more precise list of all the the built in matchers can be found here in the [API Docs to matchers](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/matchers.html).